# GCC ignores diagnostic pragmas while Clang doesn't

Tags: gcc, clang, youcompleteme

GCC 10.2.0 and Clang 11.1.0.

I have the following piece of code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
                uint8_t hour = p[8];
                uint8_t min = p[9];
                uint8_t sec = p[10];
                uint16_t msec = (p[11] * 4);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Clang (which is used by the YouCompleteMe (YCM) [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) plugin) honors these pragmas and doesn't show any warning during file processing. I can confirm that by commenting these pragmas out - YCM diagnostics immediately show me warnings on corresponding lines.

However, GCC ignores them and I get the following in the console log:

```
packet.c:111:26: warning: unused variable ‘msec’ [-Wunused-variable]
  111 |                 uint16_t msec = (p[11] * 4);
      |                          ^~~~
packet.c:110:25: warning: unused variable ‘sec’ [-Wunused-variable]
  110 |                 uint8_t sec = p[10];
      |                         ^~~
packet.c:109:25: warning: unused variable ‘min’ [-Wunused-variable]
  109 |                 uint8_t min = p[9];
      |                         ^~~
packet.c:108:25: warning: unused variable ‘hour’ [-Wunused-variable]
  108 |                 uint8_t hour = p[8];
      |                         ^~~~
```

Flags used for build:

```
CFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -Wall -pedantic -Werror=format-security" CXXFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -Wall -pedantic -Werror=format-security" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now"
```

What is going on here? It seems like a bug in GCC.

It seems like this is the case even for this simplest program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
    int x;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

    return 0;
}
```

Tests:

```
cd /tmp
clang -Wall main.c
gcc -Wall main.c

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:9: warning: unused variable ‘x’ [-Wunused-variable]
    4 |     int x;
      |         ^
```

[Some similar bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431) is described for g++ and still opened for about nine years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's related to the scoping. When I move push/pop `#pragma`s outside of a variable's block, GCC behaves well. For example:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
                uint8_t hour = p[8];
                uint8_t min = p[9];
                uint8_t sec = p[10];
                uint16_t msec = (p[11] * 4);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

should be changed to the:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
            {
                uint8_t hour = p[8];
                uint8_t min = p[9];
                uint8_t sec = p[10];
                uint16_t msec = (p[11] * 4);
            }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Then both Clang and GCC work fine.